# Screen saver in Mint 21.1

Tags: linux-mint, screen-lock, screensaver

I have two separate computers, one a lenovo desktop, the other a dell workstation, but recently reloaded with Mint 21.1 and both having rte same issue. Lenovo is Intel Iris, Dell is Nvidia if that seems relevant.

I have the screensaver set to blank to lock the screen after periods of inactivity longer than 15 minutes. Most of the time it works exactly as expected. But I have had instances when for instance, I would leave my laptop open all night and in the morning see it was still open where I left, and active (can see clock ticking, new emails, etc)

As soon as I interact with it in any way, press a key or touch the mouse, it locks.

That would be enough to stop someone from doing anything to it, but there is potential threat in being able to observe it unlocked as well, sensitive data from text messages, emails, and more, so I have been manually locking to avoid this.

I could see a process hanging and preventing start, but I cannot see user interaction clearing that condition.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot, so I know what exactly to maybe report to devs if found would be greatly appreciated. Since I cannot recreate it reliably, a non customized default install running for a month hoping to pin it on build would not be practical. So looking for any other suggestions.

I would say this has happened between the two systems a total of 5ish times in the last month.

Thank you.